# Delimiting string in bash ignoring delimiters in quotes

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I don't suppose there's a way to get this command to ignore the comma within quotes (between the 'three's)?

```
$ echo 'one,two,"three,three",four' | { IFS=',' read -a array; echo ${#array[@]}; }
5
```

Nb. `echo ${#array[@]}` reports array length..

Comment: You're essentially trying to parse a CSV format using the shell. At a stretch, GNU awk can do it but just use a CSV parser in a scripting language, e.g. perl, python or ruby.

Comment: Yes Rscript can do it: `Rscript -e "print(length(scan(text='$(echo 'one,two,\"three,three\",four')',what='character',sep=',',quiet=T)))"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `FPAT` in gnu-awk you can do it:

```
str='one,two,"three,three",four'

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{
   print "# of columns: " NF; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) print "Field #", i, ":", $i
}' <<< "$str"
```

**Output:**

```
# of columns: 4
Field # 1 : one
Field # 2 : two
Field # 3 : "three,three"
Field # 4 : four
```

Comment: NIce. I didn't about `FPAT` yet.

Comment: OK I can't deny you the tick for that one!

Answer (score 1):

Escape the comma:

```
echo 'one,two,"three\,three",four'
```

Result:

```
$ echo 'one,two,"three\,three",four' | { IFS=',' read -a array; echo ${#array[@]} ${array[2]}; }
4 "three,three"
```

Comment: Alas I can't escape the comma